# Html hidden div overlays

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so I was wondering if there is a way for me to make something that when I hover over the div, it will show a hidden div. I am using twitter bootstrap and here is my div that I want to do this with.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h2>This is the title of the first info</h2>
                    <h5>Hover to see info</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap you can use a popover for this:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Otherwise you can use jQuery to do a generic hide/show:

```
$('.hover-element').on('hover',
  function () {
    $('.hidden-element').show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $('.hidden-element').hide();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward with CSS selectors:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>This is the title of the first info</h2>
    <h5>Hover to see info</h5>
    <div class="myHiddenDiv"></div>
</div>
```

```
.myHiddenDiv {
   display: none
}

.jumbotron:hover .myHiddenDiv {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have know HTML and CSS for a while. HOwever I got out of it but now I'm back in.